# Create Group ID by Sequential Row Values

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

From a larger data set, I am subsetting out specific rows that meet a particular condition (ID is "2", which is col2 in the sample).

The subsetted data I have is similar to this sample:

```
col1 = c("17:23", "16:17", "16:08", "16:05", "15:58", "6:33", "6:04", "6:02", "5:59", "5:55", "5:41", "2:01", "1:55", "1:30")
col2 = c("2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2")

col3 = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "1", "2", "3")

test.df = cbind(col1, col2, col3) %>% as.data.frame()
```

Before I subset, I create a rolling sequence ID ("col3") that identifies rows that are sequential in the larger dataframe. Now, in this smaller subsetted dataframe, I want to create a new ID for each sequence that is grouped (i.e., where the difference != 1 between rows in col3).

Final result:

```
col1   col2  col3  ID
17:23   2     1    1
16:17   2     2    1
16:08   2     3    1
16:05   2     4    1
15:58   2     5    1
6:33    2     1    2
6:04    2     2    2
6:02    2     3    2
 [...]
2:01    2     1    3
```

etc.

Comment: It's not clear to me what your question is: Is it about how to create `col3`, or how to create `ID`, or both? Or something different?

Comment: `test.df %>% group_by(col2) %>% mutate(col3 = as.integer(col3), ID = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(col3) != 1)))`

Comment: @Jaap I spent 20 minutes looking for it but couldn't find that exact post you reference as a duplicate up above. It is indeed a duplicate as the answer is in it that one, but yours works as well, thank you for your help.